# Phoenix - JSON API 406 Not Acceptable response

Tags: json, serialization, http-headers, phoenix-framework, http-status-code-406

I started a brand new Phoenix project and am using [JASerializer](https://github.com/AgilionApps/ja_serializer) for my JSON API. I followed the documentation for what to add to my project, so I have:

**config/config.esx**

```
config :phoenix, :format_encoders,
  "json-api": Poison

config :plug, :mimes, %{
  "application/vnd.api+json" => ["json-api"]
}
```

**web/router.ex**

```
pipeline :api do
  plug :accepts, ["json-api"]
  plug JaSerializer.ContentTypeNegotiation
  plug JaSerializer.Deserializer
end
```

And I used the JSON API Generator:

```
mix ja_serializer.gen.phoenix_api User users first_name:string last_name:string username:string email:string bio:text
```

I'm using Postman to test my requests, and here's what I see when I add some headers to it:

```
Accept */* returned a 200
Accept application/vnd.api+json returned a 406
Accept application/* returned a 406
```

So in my Phoenix server console, it's outputting:

> [debug] ** (Phoenix.NotAcceptableError) no supported media type in
>   accept header, expected one of ["json-api"]

I tried deleting the _build folder and recompiling the plugs which seemed to have work for some people, but not me.

What DID work was removing `plug JaSerializer.ContentTypeNegotiation` in my router, but that seems like an important piece that I shouldn't have to remove.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Here's the link to the Issue I submitted on the `ja_serializer` repo which might be helpful: https://github.com/AgilionApps/ja_serializer/issues/138#issuecomment-232998259